emulator is not showing in the screen it is on the taskbar
im trying to open my android emulator in vs code , in android studio my emulator is opening in the running device in vs code my tablet emulator is running and showing in my screen but for mobile emulator when i start it it come and disappear only shown in the taskbar its active and connect with vs code but not showing in the display i tried shift +ctrl and right nothing shown and restart emualtor restart pc and even delete the avd and created mulatiple all are getting the same by stick on task but not showing in the dispay
i tired to open it and want to see it in the display but it only on the taskbar
